# Open a project in pycharm outside of home directory

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, pycharm, nfs

Due to a problem with vagrant's NFS on my encrypted home directory, I moved my project outside of the home directory so it can properly sync with my VM.

From the vagrant documentation:

> **Encrypted folders:** If you have an encrypted disk, then NFS very often
>   will refuse to export the filesystem. The error message given by NFS
>   is often not clear. One error message seen is "*path does not support
>   NFS*". There is no workaround for this other than sharing a directory
>   which is not encrypted.

Now, I would like to open this project in pycharm, but when I select it from the "open project" link on the splash screen, it just goes back to the splash screen without opening it. Is there some kind of configuration I need to do to allow projects from outside of /home? I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try and run Pycharm from the command line with superuser permissions, to do that:

1. In Pycharm go to *Tools* > *Create Command Line Launcher*
2. On the window that shows, define the path that you want the application to create the launcher.
3. For convenience open your `~/.bashrc` file and add the following line at the end:

   `alias Pycharm="/path/to/pycharm/com-line-executable"`
4. source your `.bashrc` file: `source ~/.bashrc`
5. `sudo Pycharm`

After that, it may be able to let you open encrypted files

Comment: Thanks! All I needed was superuser permissions.

Comment: Good to know :)